# How to enable CORS for .NET API

Tags: reactjs, .net, cors, fetch-api

I have an application with React front-end and .NET as API using fetch.

In App.js I have:

```
 var myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        myHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

        var raw = JSON.stringify({
            "userText": e.target.value
        });

        var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: raw,
            redirect: 'follow',
        };

        fetch("https://localhost:7101/api/Game/UserText", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(result => console.log(result))
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

and for my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UserText")]
        public IActionResult GetUserText([FromBody] UserText userText)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(userText.userText);
            return Ok();
        }
```

and in program.cs:

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("*");
                      });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

I have tried a few things but the error is always the same. Also tried to install the extension for Chrome but the error also stays.

The error message is:
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:7101/api/Game/UserText' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
:7101/api/Game/UserText:1

```
   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not provided the error anywhere, but I assume its `CORS error` you are talking about.

Have you tried allowing all `Headers`, `Methods` etc as below?

```
var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("*")
                              .AllowAnyHeader()
                              .AllowAnyMethod()
                              .AllowCredentials();
                      });
});

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

Note: If you have the specific values for these parameters, its always recommended to use them. For instance, instead of `WithOrigins("*")`, it should be the `WithOrigins(urls)` which should have access to the site.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't worked. I specified the url as well, as you suggested. I have included the error message now.

Comment: Ohh. The only other thing I can think of is adding `.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)` instead of `WithOrigins("*")`.